# Get id form another table, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a table test having fields 'user_id' and 'post_id'. user_id I fetch by current_user.id and post_id from the post table. For this I do:
In test controller:-

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @test = Test.new(params[:test])
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @test.post_id = @post.id
  @test.user_id = @user.id
respond_to do |format|
   @test.save
   format.html { redirect_to(:back, :notice => "successfull") }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
  end
end
```

In my Models, I create association:-

In test.rb:

```
 belongs_to :post
```

In post.rb:

```
has_many :test
```

The View page is:

```
 = form_for @test, :validate => true do |f|
   .span
     = f.text_field :email, :placeholder =>"Email Address"
   .span
     = f.label :name
     = f.text_field :name
   .span
     = f.submit "Save"
```

The user_id save properly but for post_id it give error:

```
 Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

How can I resolve that problem ?

Comment: Are you sure you should access the `create` method only when you are login i.e. `current_user` should not be nil

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you should access the create method only when you are login i.e. current_user should not be nil.

If you are getting this error in `create` method only then it should be on line

```
@test.user_id = @user.id
```

this is because `@user` is nil, and you are calling `.id` on `nil`.

EDITED

You need to send post_id from your form, assuming you are getting post object in @post

Add following line your view

```
= form_for @test, :validate => true do |f|
    = hidden_field_tag "post_id", @post.id
```

and update

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

with

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
```

Comment: Hey @Salil thanks for your response ..there is issue regarding current_user because this action is use only if user is loged in. The main issue is that, I'm not able to save post_id

Comment: you are saying `@post` is `nil` but that is not the case because `find` method in `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` will throw error like `Cannot find Post with id ###` so just check that your id is proper as well as `current_user` should `not be nil`

Comment: Sorry,This message is showing on browser.[Couldn't find Post without an ID]

Comment: It means you are giving wrong id in your url, OR common mistakes by beginner you are passing user is and finding post using it.So, you have to find out whether you are giving correct id or not

Comment: I have a post table and I'm fetching id from that table and I already check id by using Post.find(params[:id]) and Post.find(params[:post_id]), but both are not work for me.

Comment: you have to send parameter from your views to controller action, can you please edit the question with the code on your `views`?

Comment: Ok I send my view page Please check!

Answer (score 1):

Is the standard message in Rails that tells you that you tried to invoke `.id` on a `nil` value.

I suspect your `current_user` is `nil`. You can be sure by `raise current_user.inspect` i think which will tell you that its nil

You be sure you are logged in so that your `current_user` is not nil

Comment: Hey @bilash, the occur due to post_id not save in my test table , It not able to get post id from post table.there is no issue of current_user as user is logged in.please help if you have any idea. Thanks for response.